# How do I union/merge two Collections by their 'id' using UnderscoreJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I have two collections (Menu and Orders)

**Menu collection** contains array of Item objects

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'apple'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'orange'}]
```

And **Orders collection** also contains array of Item objects

```
[{'id': '1', 'quantity': '0'}]
```

And I want them merged together their attributes by ID into another collection (this is needed for templating purposes only):

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'apple', 'quantity': '1'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'orange'}]
```

Is there a underscore method on this or I need to define a function for this? [it seems i tried all merging functions on underscore but none of them works the way I expected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your collections are Backbone collections

```
var menus = new Backbone.Collection([
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'apple'}, 
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'orange'}
]);

var orders = new Backbone.Collection([{'id': '1', 'quantity': 1}]);
```

you can take advantage of the functions proxied on collections and of [`collection.get`](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-get) :

```
var merged = menus.map(function(menu) {
    var id = menu.get('id'),
        order = orders.get(id);

    if (!order) return menu.toJSON();

    return _.extend(menu.toJSON(), order.toJSON());
});
```

And a Fiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/bs6jN/

Comment: yeah, thanks for this, it also includes other attributed of the Order Collection through _.extend

Answer (score 6):

Don't think there is a function defined in underscore.js for this but one way to do it is by using the [_.map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and [_.find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) functions as follows,

```
var menus = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'apple'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'orange'}];

var orders = [{'id': '1', 'quantity': '0'}];

var newMenu = _.map(menus, function (menu) {  
    var order = _.find(orders, function (o) { 
        return o.id == menu.id;
    }); 
    return _.extend(menu, order); 
});

console.log(newMenu);
```

Comment: Also you can use _.findWhere() method with its' callback shorthand:
_.findWhere(orders, {id: menu.id});

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
var result = [];
_.each(menu, function(el){
    _.extend(el,_.where(orders, {id: el.id})[0] || {});
    result.push(el);
});
```

Comment: Excellent. I used this to merge an array of fetched results with decoration data from a second HTTP request (promises FTW). Thanks @mamoo!

Answer (score 2):

If it is an union you want to do, you can do it using the underscore way:

```
// collectionUnion(*arrays, iteratee)
function collectionUnion() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var it = args.pop();

    return _.uniq(_.flatten(args, true), it);
}
```

It just an improvment of the original function `_.union(*arrays)`, adding an iteratee to work collection (array of object).

Here how to use it:

```
var result = collectionUnion(a, b, c, function (item) {
    return item.id;
});
```

The original function which is just working with array, looks like that:

```
_.union = function() {
  return _.uniq(flatten(arguments, true, true));
};
```

And in bonus a full example:

```
// collectionUnion(*arrays, iteratee)
function collectionUnion() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var it = args.pop();

    return _.uniq(_.flatten(args, true), it);
}

var a = [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}];
var b = [{id: 2}, {id: 3}];
var c = [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}];

var result = collectionUnion(a, b, c, function (item) {
    return item.id;
});

console.log(result); // [ { id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 } ]
```

EDIT: I wrote a blog post if you want more details: http://geekcoder.org/union-of-two-collections-using-underscorejs/

Answer (score 1):

We ca merge with plain js like this

```
    var arrOne = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'apple'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'orange'}];
    var arrTwo = [{'id': '1','quantity': '0'}];

    function mergeArr(arrOne, arrTwo) {
        var mergedArr = [];
        arrOne.forEach(function (item) {
            var O = item;
            arrTwo.forEach(function (itemTwo) {
                if (O.id === itemTwo.id) {
                    O.quantity = itemTwo.quantity;

                }
            });
            mergedArr.push(O);

        });

        return mergedArr;
    }
```