# Backbone Collections - Union Two Collections at the Collection Level

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

I have two separate collections in my sample applications.  What I am trying to do is union the collections by userId.  I've handled this in the past typically at the render level, however I'd really like to resolve the data at the collection level and have render be "dumb" if you will and simple pass the data to my underscore template.

I've came across a few threads that where this was answered however I was not able to get this done at the collection level.

I've set up a plunker here to describe the situation better.
http://plnkr.co/edit/UCAFycdmsLaD14cYgTdZ?p=preview

First I do a fetch on the user collection to get all the userId's and information to resolve with the workout collection.

**users.json**

```
[
    {
        "user" : 53,
        "firstname" : "Todd",
        "lastname" : "Jones",
        "email" : "xxx@gmail.com",
        "avatar" : ""
    },
    {
        "user" : 53,
        "firstname" : "Sarah",
        "lastname" : "Thomas",
        "email" : "xxx@gmail.com",
        "avatar" : ""
    }
]
```

**tracker.json**

```
[
    {
        "user" : 53,
        "distance" : 3,
        "duration" : 180000,
        "date" : "November 27, 2014 09:45:00",
        "felt" : "Tired at first"
    },
    {
        "user" : 53,
        "distance" : 3.256,
        "duration" : 978600,
        "date" : "November 28, 2014 10:15:00",
        "felt" : "Great"
    }
]
```

I've seen a few examples in this thread [How do I union/merge two Collections by their 'id' using UnderscoreJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433605/how-do-i-union-merge-two-collections-by-their-id-using-underscorejs)

However I believe my problem is that I am trying to access the UserCollection within the WorkoutCollection incorrectly, or that I haven't resolve it to a JSON object (this happened in the render function).

Entire code is below and plunker is here http://plnkr.co/edit/UCAFycdmsLaD14cYgTdZ?p=preview

Thank in advance for any insight.

```
// Users Model
var Users = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function() {
        return {
            avatar: "" // generic Avatar if none supplied by users
        };
    }

});

// Workouts Collection
var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model : Users,
    url: '/data/users.json',
    parse: function (responses) {
        return responses;
    }

});
// Workouts Model
var Workouts = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function() {
        return {
            felt: "Good"
        };
    },

});

// Workouts Collection
var WorkoutCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model : Workouts,
    url: '/data/tracker.json',
    parse: function (responses) {

        var data = [];
        _.each(responses, function(response){

            // format durations
            var x = response.duration;
            var d = moment.duration(x, 'milliseconds');
            var hours = Math.floor(d.asHours());
            var mins = Math.floor(d.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;
            var seconds = Math.floor(d.asSeconds()) - mins * 60;
            var duration = "";

            if (hours > 0) {
                duration += hours + " hours ";
            }

            if (mins > 0) {
                duration += mins + " minutes ";
            }

            if (seconds > 0) {
                duration += seconds + " seconds ";
            }

            response.duration = duration;

            // format workout dates
            var y = response.date;
            var z = moment(y).format('dddd, MMM Do YYYY');

            response.date = z;
        });

        var result = [];
        _.each(responses, function(el){
            console.log(el)
            console.log(UserCollection.get("user"))
            _.extend(el,_.where(UserCollection, {user: el.user})[0] || {});
            result.push(el);
        });

        console.log(result);

      return responses;
    }
});

// Main
var ExerciseApp = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: "#exercise_app",
    template: null,

    initialize: function() {

        this.userCollection = new UserCollection();
        this.listenTo(this.userCollection, "reset sync remove", this.usersLoaded);
        this.userCollection.fetch({dataType: "json"});

    },

    usersLoaded: function() {

        this.workoutCollection = new WorkoutCollection();
        this.listenTo(this.workoutCollection, "reset sync remove", this.render);
        this.workoutCollection.fetch({dataType: "json"});
        this.template = _.template($('#workout-table-template').html());

    },

    render: function() {

        var workouts = this.workoutCollection.toJSON();
        var users = this.userCollection.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template({workouts: workouts, users: users}));

    },

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var app = new ExerciseApp
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have this working the way I'd like it to.

What I ended up doing was passing the users collection to the workouts collection.

I then was easily able to merge the data using underscores _map function.

```
usersLoaded: function() {

    var users = this.userCollection.toJSON();
    this.workoutCollection = new WorkoutCollection(users);
    this.listenTo(this.workoutCollection, "reset sync remove", this.render);
    this.workoutCollection.fetch({dataType: "json"});
    this.template = _.template($('#workout-table-template').html());

},

parse: function (responses) {

    var workouts = responses;
    var users = this.users;

    var mergedCollection = _.map(users, function (user) {  
        var workout = _.find(workouts, function (o) { 
            return o.userId == user.userId;
        }); 
        return _.extend(user, workout); 
    });


    _.each(mergedCollection, function(response){

        // format durations
        var x = response.duration;
        var d = moment.duration(x, 'milliseconds');
        var hours = Math.floor(d.asHours());
        var mins = Math.floor(d.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;
        var seconds = Math.floor(d.asSeconds()) - mins * 60;
        var duration = "";

        if (hours > 0) {
            duration += hours + " hours ";
        }

        if (mins > 0) {
            duration += mins + " minutes ";
        }

        if (seconds > 0) {
            duration += seconds + " seconds ";
        }

        response.duration = duration;

        // format workout dates
        var y = response.date;
        var z = moment(y).format('dddd, MMM Do YYYY');

        response.date = z;
    });

  return mergedCollection;
}
```